# Instructions per second for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

This is a bit of a generic question.
I am working on an iOS cocoa-2d game which involves complex path finding algorithms. The game is turn based. So before each user's turn I would like to calculate all possible paths. This involves running a lot of data manipulation commands and allocate and releasing simple data objects (no I/O) I am guessing about a million instructions are required to calculate all the paths each turn. Could the iPhone 3GS, 4 and 4G perform this at a fraction of a second, assuming the game is using a single thread.

In general how many instructions per second can be achieved within the game. I am looking for a guesstimate very high level figure.

Comment: No expensive commands will be used such as square root or power of commands.

Comment: `assuming the game is using a single thread` Why not use another thread to do those calculation in? Your app isn't the only thing using system resources and you don't want your user to sit there with a frozen (or dead, killed by the WatchDog) app. Furthermore, some Apple frameworks can take advantage of the GPU of a device depending on what you're using, such as Apple's Accelerate framework and some parts of Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: Also do not comment on your question as a way of adding information to it. Click the edit link to edit the question and add the information directly.

Comment: The reason I would like it in a single thread is because the user cannot start their turn before the calculations are finished.

Comment: Also cocos2d already uses openGL which I believe uses GPU?

Comment: Even an approximation will be nearly impossible to arrive at here, given the number of variables involved (floating point vs. integer, NEON acceleration or no, C types or Objective-C objects, etc.). My recommendation is to build a simple test case for this pathfinding and profile it yourself on the target hardware. Only then will you have a basis for scaling this up.

Comment: @plawres `the user cannot start their turn before the calculations are finished.` Your second thread should simply call back to the main thread when it's finished. If your app freezes for an arbitrary amount of time, the WatchDog process will kill it on the device in a release build. Also sure, cocos2d uses OpenGL, but only for drawing. All of your math and stuff is still done in the CPU.

Comment: Ok. So you are suggesting to use multi-threading which is fair enough. I do not know much about the accelarate fra

Comment: Ok. So you are suggesting to use multi-threading which is fair enough. I do not know much about the accelarate frame and it seems to be doing dsp, image and vector processing which seems like an overkill for a game. Also what else can I do to make this goal achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This greatly depends on the type of "instructions" used in your algorithm or calculation, how they are scheduled by your compiler, and how you count them.

In extremely rough and coarse terms, the ARM CPUs currently used by Apple can issue on the order of 1 integer instruction per clock cycle, and the ARM processor cores used in iOS devices reportedly range in clock speed from 400 MHz to 1 GHz.  A high ratio of floating point, multiply or divide instructions or cache misses may significantly change the actual instruction issue and retirement rate.

But the best way to get an accurate estimate would be to compile and benchmark your actual code on your target iOS device.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's the best way to tell anyway. I am just trying to get a feel of the speed of the CPU. I understand that it is very broad question and will depend on many factors. Thanks.